# Sylow subgroup: Am I right?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm working on 4.5.33 of Dummit&Foote; Let $P$ be a normal Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$ and let $H$ be any subgroup of $G$. Prove that $P \cap H$ is the unique Sylow $p$-subgroup of $H$.

Here is my solution: Suppose $|G|=p^n m$ and $|H|=p^t s$. ($(p,m)=(p,s)=1$) Then $t \leq n$ and $s$ divides $m$. Furthermore, since $|P \cap H|$ divides both $|P|=p^n$ and $|H|=p^t s$, $|P \cap H|=p^a$ for some $a \leq t$.

Now consider the canonical projection $\pi:G \to G/P$. By restricting the domain, we get a group homomorphism $\phi:H \to G/P$.

$x \in Ker(\phi)~\Leftrightarrow~x \in P$, so $Ker(\phi)=P\cap H$. Therefore $H/(P \cap H)$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $G/P$. It means that $\frac{|H|}{|P\cap H|}$ divides $\frac{|G|}{|P|}$. Then $|H||P|=p^{n+t} s $ divides $|G||P \cap H|=p^{n+a} m~\Rightarrow~t \leq a$.

$\therefore~t=a$, i.e. $P \cap H$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $H$.

Now $P \cap H \unlhd H$, so $P \cap H$ is the unique Sylow $p$-subgroup of $H$, by the second Sylow's theorem.

========================

I'm not sure of my solution. Is there any problem in this solution?

Comment: Your proof looks fine.